# Does this "in" mean "inside" or "into" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It was just then that Mr. Jones woke up. The next moment he and his four men were **in** the store-shed with whips in their hands, lashing out in all directions.

According to the meanings in dictionaries, *in* could mean either *inside* or *into*. In this sentence above both of them make sense. I found that all the examples below the article *into* in dictionaries are preceded with a notional verb, which is not the case in this sentence. So which meaning is more suitable here?

Comment: Here, it means **inside**.

Comment: Obviously they must have gone _into_ the shed, but the narrative jumps forward from the moment of Mr Jones waking to the time when they are already _inside_ the shed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence describes a state: the five men are in the shed. It means they are inside that building.

*Into* has a directional, transitional element to it. The men were outside. They went/ran/sneaked *into* the shed. Now they are inside.